# No carga correctamente Angular Js en internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

tengo el siguiente problema al querer cargar una url en internet explorer.
al cargar mi pagina con angular 1.5 en mozila, carga normal.
luego copio la url de mi pagina en mozila y la pego en internet explorer esto muestra el html sin haber cargado angular al parecer, osea me muestra las llaves donde deberia haber cargado los datos obtenidos desde el servicio rest.
todo funciona ok despues de darle Ctrl + F5.

alguna sugerencia por favor

Comment: sugiero que coloques tu código :D

Answer (score 1):

Muy probablemente, tu versión de angular no sea compatible con la de Internet Explorer que estas usando.

Te dejo un enlace con información al respecto:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie